# Adaptive Server connection failed python 3 with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-sql-database, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to run below code on python 3 shell. OS : Ubuntu 16.04

```
import pymssql

DB_SERVER = 'server endpoint'
DB_USER = 'user information'
DB_PWD = 'password'
DB_DATABASE = 'databasename'
conn = pymssql.connect(server=DB_SERVER,user=DB_USER,password=DB_PWD,database=DB_DATABASE)
```

> Error: 
>   File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed)

Comment: If you get this error, before descending into dependency hell, try a shorter password. No combination of TDS or pymssql worked for me on 14.04 when the password length was 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pymssql library uses a bundled FreeTDS installation. This FreeTDS install does not contain support for SSL which is required for Azure SQL and gives a problem on Ubuntu 16.04+ (14.04 works fine though). In order to make it work, compile and build FreeTDS with SSL support and then install pymssql using this version of FreeTDS. The steps below describe the process:

#### 1. Install OpenSSL

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

#### 2. Install FreeTDS with SSL support

NOTE: This example uses current latest FreeTDSversion (freetds-1.00.9). Replace it in the instructions below with latest version

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.00.9.tar.gz
$ gunzip freetds-1.00.9.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf freetds-1.00.9.tar
$ cd freetds-1.00.9.tar
$ sudo ./configure --with-openssl='/usr/lib/ssl'
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

#### 3. Install pymssql from source with a flag to not use bundled FreeTDS

```
$ export PYMSSQL_DONT_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1
$ sudo -H pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git
```

Comment: I'm getting error while executing `sudo -H pip install git+https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql.git`

Comment: remove .tar to make cd command work. `cd freetds-1.00.9.tar` to `cd freetds-1.00.9`

Answer (score 1):

pymssql 2.1.1 works (without the need of custom freetds build with ssl)